# How to create JFreeChart control with JavaBuilders?

Tags: java, yaml, jfreechart, miglayout, javabuilders

How can I create a JFreeChart control in YAML, using JavaBuilder?

My current form YAML follows:

```
JFrame(name=frame, title=frame.title, size=packed, defaultCloseOperation=exitOnClose):
    - JLabel(name=sortLabel, text=label.sorttext)
    - JComboBox(name=sortComboBox, editable=false)
    - JScrollPane(name=listScrollpane, vScrollBar=always, hScrollBar=never):
        JList(name=batteryList)
    - JButton(name=exitButton, text=button.exit, onAction=[$confirm,cancel])
    - JPanel(name=graphPanel)
    - MigLayout: |
        [[fill]]
        []                  [grow]           [grow]
        sortLabel           sortComboBox     graphPanel
        listScrollpane+2
        exitButton
```

I tried both `JFreeChart` or `ChartPanel` in place of `JPanel(name=graphPanel)`, but I keep getting this error during debugging: *"JFreeChart is not a recognized alias."*

I verified **jcommon-1.0.16.jar** and **jfreechart-1.0.13.jar** have been added to the project libraries (in NetBeans.)

Does anyone know where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you are using [javabuilders](http://code.google.com/p/javabuilders/). This library seems to be related to swing development. Hence it has defined YAML aliases for all swing classes. The JFreeChart class wont have an alias as it isn't a swing class.

There is a section on extending the javabuilders engine in this [PDF](http://javabuilders.googlecode.com/files/SwingJavaBuilder-1.1.pdf).
The following line looks helpful

```
SwingJavaBuilder.getConfig().addType("CustomClassAlias",MyCustomClass.class);
```

Sorry I can't be more specific, but I haven't really used javabuilders before.